# How to request a page every 30 minutes

Tags: asp.net, timer

This is a question regarding best practices. I hope to get some advice from other developers.

I need a page on my website to be requested at least once every 30 minutes. What I am trying to achieve is a timer that runs code I have in the web application.

There are some websites that check if your website is up, but in reality those are not reliable.

Looking forward to your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackoverflow does this... See the blog entry here:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

Basically, the have a callback function that gets called when a cached object expires. This can run whatever code you want, if you want it to load a page, you could do that with an HttpWebRequest. However, I imagine you just need some code run, so you could do that directly in the function.

Comment: I liked this approach even though I knew about it, but was pretty much sceptical about its availability as a stable one, but since stackoverflow use it and t work fine, I think thats a validity test already :).

Answer (score 3):

This problem has two parts:

1. How do you request a page once?
2. How do you run code periodically?

Once you break it down like that, it becomes simple to write a Console or Windows Forms application that can run the "request page once" code "periodically".

Answer (score 3):

### Step 1

Write a .Net console application that makes a request to the page you want to hit.

### Step 2

Use Windows Scheduler to execute your console application (i.e. your .exe) every 30 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

There is a firefox add on [Reload Every](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/115)

Could also use wget with cron or a scheduled task

You could also just write some code in a page load event where you check if > 30 minutes have passed since the last hit then run some chunk of code.

Answer (score 0):

First you can use [Grease Monkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) to inject your Timer function in the website and inject this code :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
// CREDITS:
// Automatic Page Refresher by Peter Gehrig and Urs Dudli
// Permission given to use the script provided that this notice remains as is.
// Additional scripts can be found at http://www.24fun.com & http://www.designerwiz.com
// info@24fun.com
// 8/30/2001

// IMPORTANT: 
// If you add this script to a script-library or script-archive 
// you have to add a link to http://www.24fun.com on the webpage 
// where this script will be running.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CONFIGURATION STARTS HERE

// Configure refresh interval (in seconds)
var refreshinterval=5

// Shall the coundown be displayed inside your status bar? Say "yes" or "no" below:
var displaycountdown="yes"

// CONFIGURATION ENDS HERE
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Do not edit the code below
var starttime
var nowtime
var reloadseconds=0
var secondssinceloaded=0

function starttime() {
    starttime=new Date()
    starttime=starttime.getTime()
    countdown()
}

function countdown() {
    nowtime= new Date()
    nowtime=nowtime.getTime()
    secondssinceloaded=(nowtime-starttime)/1000
    reloadseconds=Math.round(refreshinterval-secondssinceloaded)
    if (refreshinterval>=secondssinceloaded) {
        var timer=setTimeout("countdown()",1000)
        if (displaycountdown=="yes") {
            window.status="Page refreshing in "+reloadseconds+ " seconds"
        }
    }
    else {
        clearTimeout(timer)
        window.location.reload(true)
    } 
}
window.onload=starttime
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the transcript for stackoverflow podcast #15, search for [heartbeat.asp](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W13117)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Nagois](http://www.nagios.org/), it can hit your web app every 30 seconds. If this is for monitoring, I recommend the [The Holy Trinity of Web 2.0 Application Monitoring](http://www.agileatwork.com/the-holy-trinity-of-web-2-0-application-monitoring/).